# Is there a way to clone `n` amount of elements on the stack to the stack in x86_64 linux assembly?

Tags: linux, assembly, stack, x86-64, fasm

Basically you can 'remove' elements
from the stack by adding to `rsp` register
`n * 8`, but if you try the opposite (`rsp - (n * 8)`)
it doesn't work, which seems obvious but still

So if I push to the stack using `push` like this:

```
push 10
push 20
```

So the stack is basically `(20; 10)`, how could I make it
`(20; 10; 20; 10)` without needing to use registers (Because you're limited)
or needing to repeat the `push`

But if it's not possible which is better to use as an alternative,
repeating the `push` or using registers using `pop` and then pushing
them back?

Comment: If you want memory to assume a certain value, you'll have to write that value to memory.  There's no way around that.  So you'll probably have to use one of the two ways you wanted to rule out.  Pushing again is a good idea and probably ideal in the specific case you have.  Might be different in your actual case.

Comment: @fuz oh, okay, sucks, thanks for such quick answer

Comment: Just: push 10; push 20; push 10; push 20.   No registers needed (except `rsp` is involved, of course).

Comment: @ErikEidt Yep, will go for that most likely

Comment: @ErikEidt Note that RIP is also involved... and the corresponding segment registers. Possibly the MMU registers, too. But I guess those are details.

Comment: @AlexisWilke, yes of course!

Comment: If you had more than 32 bytes to set, it would be worth using SSE2.  e.g. `movaps` load a constant from `.rodata`, and `sub rsp, 32` / `movaps [rsp], xmm0` / `movaps [rsp+16], xmm0`.  Optionally compress your constant to byte elements and load it with SSE4.1 `movzxbq xmm0, word [const_10_20]` where you did `const_10_20: db 10,20`.  For runtime-variables, lots of ways you could approach this, basically doing `_mm_set_epi64x( b, a );` with movq / pinsrq or another movq + punpcklqdq.  Or if data is already in memory, loading 16 bytes is easy.  (But 2 pushes => movaps reload is a store fwd stall)

Comment: If you have many repeats, then definitely consider AVX for 32-byte stores.  Like a generalized `memset` that can work with repeating patterns of up to 16 YMM registers.

Comment: @PeterCordes I cannot link with libc

Comment: I never suggested linking with libc.  It doesn't have anything that can help you for repeating patterns longer than 4 bytes (`wmemset`), other than I guess `memcpy`.  But you wouldn't call a function for a small fixed-rep-count vector operation anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `n` and the `push`ed values are constant:

- Your question is tagged with [x86-64](/questions/tagged/x86-64), so I presume the default operand size is currently set to 64 bits.
  Your `push imm8` is pushing sign-extended quadwords.
  Unless you really need quadwords on the stack, how about putting 8 individual *Byte values* on the stack:

  ```
  push ((10 * 0x100 + 20) * 0x100 + 10) * 0x100 + 20
  mov [rsp + 4], dword ((10 * 0x100 + 20) * 0x100 + 10) * 0x100 + 20
  ```

  NB:
  In long mode it is not possible to just `push imm32` so that `rsp ≔ rsp − 4`, hence the `mov`.
- If you just want to avoid having the same constants over and over again:

  ```
  push 1234
  push 5678
  ; first copy
  push qword [rsp + 8]
  push qword [rsp + 8]
  ; second copy
  push qword [rsp + 8]
  push qword [rsp + 8]
  ```
- For `push imm8`s, however, I would simply opt for the assembler’s expansion capability:

  ```
  repeat 3
      push 10
      push 20
  end repeat
  ```

Comment: I came up with something else, I forgot what, but I don't need it anymore :) But I shall be saving this :)